# straight MySQL results vs converted to JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is there any benefit to converting results from a MySQL query to JSON instead of just manipulating the results as they are?

I am adding features to a web frontend for a MySQL database that was written in PHP and has not been touched in at least 5 years.  I want to make it a bit more modern such as adding Ajax functionality to improve the user experience.  I'm wondering if there are things that would be much easier to implement by converting results to JSON or if there are aspects of improved security that I'm not seeing.

Comment: if you are manipulating the data with PHP, then do not convert it to JSON. If you are sending the already manipulated data to the client to be read by JavaScript, then you would want to convert this into JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage to JSON is that it's easily understood by JavaScript since it is essentially raw JavaScript.  If you already have working code that converts some other form into a form understood by your JavaScript functions, then I would say don't touch it, unless you're experiencing some sort of problem with the existing code.